# Is it possible to post a url to an Opportunity in a simple chatter post?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter

I'm trying to make a chatter post that includes the Opportunity name as a URL. So basically it will be something like: [TestOpportunity](http://na.com) which would take the user to the actual Opportunity when they click on it. Right now I have it posting as text. Is this possible in a simple chatter post? Thanks in advance for the help!

**Update: I managed to get the URL using:**

```
String URL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + opp.Id;
```

**How can I put the Opportunity Name as the URL instead of the ugly URL? Possible?**

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oppOwnerId.Id;
post.createdById= oppOwnerId.Id;
post.Body = 'Opportunity ' + opp.Id; 
insert post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is something like this sufficient? The Op Name is a clickable link, though the Id is visible in the post as well.

```
Opportunity o = [Select OwnerId, Id, Name from Opportunity WHERE Id = 'xxx'];

FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = o.OwnerId;
post.createdById= o.OwnerId;
post.Type = 'LinkPost'; 
post.Title = o.Name;
post.LinkURL = '/'+ o.Id;
insert post;
```

Or do you need more of the rich text mentioned in the post you link to (which is possible via ConnectAPI if you need an example - let me know)

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note this is not a proper salesforce link to the record, it will always open in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this same question was asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/732/create-chatter-post-with-mix-of-hyperlinks-and-text-in-the-body-in-apex-code).  Not the answer you are looking for unfortunately.

Comment: yeah I saw that one. But not the answer I was looking for you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the ConnectAPI - which would look something like this:

```
Opportunity o = [Select Id, Name, OwnerId from Opportunity WHERE Id = 'xxx'];

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput linkAttach = new ConnectApi.LinkAttachmentInput();

linkAttach.URL =  URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + o.Id;
linkAttach.URLName = o.Name;

input.attachment = linkAttach;

ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItemRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.UserProfile, o.OwnerId, input, null);
```

The link is still visible in the post, but the name is now a clickable link